# Why does Jordan's lemma only hold when $|f(z)|$ approaches $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Consider the integral,
$$
I=\int_{C_R}e^{iaz}f(z)dz
$$
where $a>0$ and $C_R$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane.

Then according to Jordan's Lemma, this integral goes to zero if $|f(z)|\to0$ as $R\to \infty$. But what if $|f(z)|\to z^k$ for some $k>0$, shouldn't the integral go to $0$ in this case as well, because
$$
\begin{align}
I &=\int_{0}^\pi e^{iaR(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)}f(Re^{i\theta})Rie^{i\theta}d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^\pi e^{-aR\sin \theta} (e^{iaR\cos\theta}f(Re^{i\theta})Rie^{i\theta})d\theta
\end{align}
$$
And since $\sin \theta >0$ if $0<\theta<\pi$, $e^{-aR\sin \theta}$ produces a damped exponential which goes to $0$ faster than any positive power of $R$, the integral should go to $0$.

I think the problem arises due to the lower limit of the integral but I don't understand why the integral doesn't go to $0$ there as well because $\theta$ is never actually equal to $0$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because near the real axis the exponential is actually not that small; take $f=1$ and using Cauchy the integral $I$ is the same as the integral on the real axis, $\int_{-R}^Re^{iat}dt$ which is definitely not convergent or goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$;your argument fails because while $e^{-aR\sin \theta} \to 0, R \to \infty, \theta \ne 0, \pi$, it does so non-uniformly and for $\theta$ in the $1/R$ or lower range the $R$ from $dz$ counters the $1/R$ range

Comment: @Conrad Oh okay, thanks. So if I've understood correctly, the problem arises because of the order of the limits, $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-aR\sin\theta}d\theta \neq 0$ but $\int_{0}^{\pi}\lim_{R\to\infty}e^{-aR\sin\theta}d\theta = 0$, right?

Comment: not quite; it is $\int_{0}^{\pi}Re^{-aR\sin\theta}d\theta \ge \int_{0}^{1/R}Re^{-aR\sin\theta}d\theta \ge e^{-a}$ since $e^{-aR\sin\theta} \ge e^{-a}$ for $0 \le \theta \le 1/R$,  while the extra $R$ appears from $dz$ as you correctly noted

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about the $R$. Would my argument work if I include the $R$? i.e $\int_{0}^{\pi}\lim_{R\to\infty}Re^{-aR\sin\theta}d\theta = 0$ but $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}Re^{-aR\sin\theta}d\theta \neq 0$.

Comment: yes now is correct since $\lim_{R\to\infty}Re^{-aR\sin\theta}=0, \theta \ne 0, \pi$ and the limit is infinite at those two points but it doesn't matter as the integral goes

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for taking your time!